ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : missing "Allow-Control-Allow-Headers" headers in response
In my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I enabled CORS following this article: MS article.
The API endpoint works, but there is no expected header Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response:
API response network tab
When I tried to hit the API using an Angular client application, I got a CORS error:
Chrome: Chrome
Firefox: Firefox network tab
This is my Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "EnableCORS", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true);
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig:Token").Value)),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCors("EnableCORS");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

I have tried:
Other answer 1
Other answer 2
Other answer 3
Angular app uses this Web.config after publish to IIS:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.webServer>        
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>             
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
        <remove name="Content-Security-Policy" />        
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>             
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>


I created a simple login demo request to test your code in the program.cs from another origin, and everything is working well. I received the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response. Therefore, the issue might be in your request source code. Could you please provide the complete code of the request? By the way, the first link you provided doesn't seem to be the correct one you intended to share.

@YumiaoKong Thank you! My Angular app works fine locally (localhost) with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response. Only after publish to IIS it stopped working. So do you think the problem still might be the request from Angular ?

I used this sample code (https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/11/29/angular-14-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) to test my API, same result (CORS error).  Is it possible that the web.config that used for Angular causing this issue? (I added my web.config in the post)

If the issue is related to IIS, maybe you can try to remove the WebDav Module in web.config:
<handlers>
   <remove name="WebDAV" />
</handlers>
<modules>
   <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>

refer to this answer

Is this CORS policy in Web.config for web api or Angular client? The api already have this configured in Program.cs?

@Bing Code, Ok, you are right, you don't need to configure the CORS policy in web.config again cause you have configured it in program.cs. I have updated my answer. This issue may be related to Authentication. Could you try to rule out this possibility? Alternatively, this issue might be related to IIS configuration. Does the issue occur only with POST requests? You can try to remove the WebDav Module.
